# Changing div text value by clicking on a li item

Tags: reactjs

i want to change the text value in a `div` by clicking on a `ul` `li` item.

```
const text = { 
value1 : 'blabla1',
value2 : 'blabla2',
value3 : 'blabla3'
}

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<div> </div>
```

By clicking on `li 1` the `div` get the `value1`, by clicking on `li 2` the `div` get the `value2` etc.

Can someone give me some advice, thank you

Comment: Hey JDL, welcome to SO! Please note that StackOverflow is not a free "write-me-code" service and you should demonstrate what you have already tried in order to get help. Now this seems to be a rather straightforward thing to do. The key thing you are looking for is "component state" which allows you to change a value used for rendering and update the DOM accordingly. Then you can change the value based on the array index or a key to look the value up from the object and render it as inner value of the div.

Comment: I was just asking for advice not for a complete solution. Sorry if i was not enough clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am write code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const text = [
    { id: 1, value: "blabla1" },
    { id: 2, value: "blabla2" },
    { id: 3, value: "blabla3" }
  ];

  const [textSelected, setTextSelected] = useState("");

  const selectLi = (id) => {
    let index = text.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);
    if (index === -1) return;
    setTextSelected(text[index].value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {text.map((x) => (
          <li
            onClick={() => {
              selectLi(x.id);
            }}
          >
            {x.id}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <br />
      <div>{textSelected}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    alert("value is " + e.target.id);
    let item = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
    console.log(item.getAttribute("name"));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li id="blabla1" name="el1" onClick={clickHandler}>
          1
        </li>
        <li id="blabla2" name="el2" onClick={clickHandler}>
          2
        </li>
        <li id="blabla3" name="el3" onClick={clickHandler}>
          3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-shirley-jl6v2?file=/src/App.js). You can also assign a value to a variable by using `useState`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [listValues, setListValues] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

  const text = { value1: "blabla1", value2: "blabla2", value3: "blabla3" };

  const showTextValue = (index) => {
    const newValues = [...listValues];
    newValues[index] = Object.values(text)[index];
    setListValues(newValues);
  };

  const content = listValues.map((val, index) => (
    <li key={index} onClick={() => showTextValue(index)}>
      {val}
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>{content}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```